# Adding a large modification to web.config in a SharePoint Web Part

Tags: web-part, feature, web-config

Through various sources on the web, I've seen simple ways to modify web.config from a SharePoint feature.  However they are typically one liners.  But if I need to add a WCF Binding such as this:

```
    <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="thisName">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://thisserver" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="thisConfig" contract="thisContract" name="thisName" />
</client>
```

Not sure what would be the easiest way to do such a bulk insert.  It would be under  and most likely the entire block would have to be inserted as typically WCF bindings aren't used in web.config's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the C# following code to modify the web.config:

```
string content;
string WebServiceServer = "example.com"; // <=== your host-name here
using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(bindingFilePath))
{
    content = String.Format(tr.ReadToEnd(), WebServiceServer);
}

SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification("system.serviceModel", "configuration");
modification.Value = content;
modification.Sequence = 0;
modification.Type =SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
modification.Owner = OWNER_CONSTANT;

webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);
```

I spent some time figuring it out. Hope this will help someone.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147439/adding-web-service-bindings-into-sharepoint-web-config-using-spwebconfigmodifica

http://sharepointtrivedi.blogspot.com/2012/06/sharepoint-feature-to-add-webconfig.html